# Periodic Arrays

Tags: code-golf, math

## Challenge

The challenge is to write a function that prints the number of **repeats** a given array of integers has.

#### What are repeats?

Repeats of a slice (as in a section of an array) `[ a1, a2, a3, ..., an]` are any other non-overlapping slices of the forms `[ a1+an, a2+an, a3+an, ..., an+an]`, `[ a1+2an, a2+2an, a3+2an, ..., an+2an]`, and so on. Incomplete repeats, e.g. `[ a1+3an, a2+3an]`, are not counted.

#### Input and output

Inputs should be ordered collections of integers, e.g. arrays, lists, tuples, etc. The integers will be sorted and unique.

Output a single integer that is the number of repeats that covers the whole input. The output should correspond to the greatest possible number of repeats. E.g. certain inputs could be modeled to have 3 repeats of a 4-element slice, or 6 repeats of a 2-element slice; 6 should be the output because it is greater than 3.

## Examples

```
Input -> Output

[ 1,  3,  5,
  6,  8, 10,
 11, 13, 15,
 16, 18, 20]
-> 4

[ 3,  5, 7, 10,
 13, 15]
-> 1

[1,
 2,
 3]
-> 3

[1,2,4]
-> 1

[ 3, 5, 7, 9,
 12,14,16,18]
-> 2
```

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so the shortest code possible wins

If you have any questions related to the challenge feel free to ask.
I know that my attempts to explain something can be difficult to understand sometimes.

Comment: As far as I can see the challenge is roughly: "What is the maximum number of equal sized chunks into which an array can be split so that the difference between corresponding elements in any chunk and the next chunk (if any) is a constant. The array is a sorted list of positive (?) numbers (the minumum number of elements is not yet clear)

Comment: @TonHospel: That would return `5` for the initial example: `[5,8],[7,10],[8,11],[15,18],[17,20]` differ by 3 and `[1,11],[5,15],[7,17],[8,18],[10,20]` differ by 10. Maybe the indexes count too? Still, we have a difference of 10 in `5` pairs. And `[5,8,11,17,20]`?

Comment: @Titus: The chunks consist of consecutive elements in the original array and the difference must be a constant over chunks too (otherwise an array of length n can always be split in n). Anyways, I hope this gets clarified and reopened. If my interpretation is correct this is actually a fun little challenge. I have a perl solution just itching to be posted.

Comment: Why does the second example give `1` and not `3`?

Comment: "Find maximum number of equal sized chunks where the delta in the columns is equal and the same in all columns" is a little bulky

Comment: @Titus I chose a bad example... I updated it again to hopefully be correct this time

Comment: @RoiEX just wanna introduce you the sandbox: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/ Next time when you come up with a challenge, you can use it to let other users find problems or bugs in your challenge before actually posting it :-)

Comment: 1. What is a *slice*? The elements at any arithmetic progression of indices? 2. Why does the last test case not have output `2`? It seems to me that `[1]` repeats as `[2]` (and `[2]` repeats as `[4]`, but `max(2, 2) = 2`). 3. How about some test cases with non-trivial gaps between the repeats, etc.?

Comment: @PeterTaylor 1) Basically an array slice. 2) that would make two sequences overlap. 3) The gaps are fixed to be `an`.

Comment: 1. That doesn't answer my question. I want a definition, not a repetition. 2. How? They're disjoint. 3. I'm talking about gaps in the indices, not gaps in the values.

Comment: @PeterTaylor 1) For the sake of this question a definition like "a section of the whole sequence" might work. 2&3) OP should probably explicitly state that: you can assume all input to consist only of repetitions, complete or not. For question 2, this means you can't treat `2` and `4` without including `1` as part of the repetition, or `1` and `2` without `4`(`[1,2,...]` needs to continue with `3` if it were a part of a repetition).

Comment: @RoiEX You might want to explicitly state in the "Output" section that "you can assume that all input consists only of repetitions, whereas the final repetition can be incomplete."

Comment: Does a slice consist only of contiguous elements?  In Python, a slice could refer to, say, every second element.

Comment: Would [1,3,4,6,11] give 2 or 1?

Comment: @xnor Example `[1,2,4]` gives 1, so `[1,3,4,6,11]` should also give 1

Comment: Still to be clarified: Can the input array contain `0` ? negative values ? Is a single integer as input allowed. In particular is a single `0` allowed ? If the intention is non-negative integers then `0` is still weird since it can then only appear at the start, so it becomes `a1`, but then the next repeat must start with `a1+an` which is `an` which is therefore a repeat of the previious number which is forbidden. So starting with `0` implies only 1 repeat (simular argument for starting with a negative number). So it seems more logical to only allow positive integers in the input

Comment: One of my three questions has been answered (although not by the OP, so I hope they agree with the edits), but the other two haven't.

Comment: I just noticed that there is no test case where the gaps within each chunk vary (e.g. `[1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 9, 11, 14, 15, 16, 18, 21]`, which I think should give `3`). This should probably be added if I've got it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>21</s> 20 bytes

```
0)«¥©v®NôÙgi®Nôg}})Z
```

**Explanation**

```
0)«                   # prepend a 0 to the beginning of the list
   ¥©                 # calculate deltas and store in register
     v           }    # for each N in range(0, len(deltas))
      ®Nô             # split deltas into N chunks
         Ù            # uniquify list
          gi    }     # if length == 1
            ®Nôg      # push chunk length
                  )Z  # return max chunk length
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=MCnCq8Klwql2wq5Ow7TDmWdpwq5Ow7RnfX0pWg&input=WyAxLCAgMywgIDUsICA2LCAgOCwgMTAsIDExLCAxMywgMTUsIDE2LCAxOCwgMjBd)

[Modified test suite](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=fHYwwrh5I8KrwqXCqWdGwq5Ow7TDmWdpwq5Ow7RnfX0pWixc&input=MSAzIDUgNiA4IDEwIDExIDEzIDE1IDE2IDE4IDIwCjMgNSA3IDEwIDEzIDE1CjEgMiAzCjEgMiA0CjMgNSA3IDkgMTIgMTQgMTYgMTg)

Answer (score 4):

## Perl, <s>48</s> 47 bytes

Includes +3 for `-p`

Give input as a list of numbers on STDIN

```
repeats.pl <<< "3 5 7 9 12 14 16 18"
```

`repeats.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
s//0 /;s/\d+/$'-$&/eg;/(.+?)\1*-/;$_=s/$1//g
```

Does not work if the input is a single 0 (not clear if that is a valid input). Fixing that takes 2 more bytes:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
$_=s//0 /%s/\d+/$'-$&/eg-/^(.+?)\1*-/||s/$1//g
```

### Explanation

Adds a 0 in front of the sequence and then constructs a list of differences. The example input

```
3 5 7 9 12 14 16 18
```

becomes:

```
3 2 2 2 3 2 2 2 -18
```

The -18 is because the last difference is calculated relative to the end of the string which in perl will behave like 0. On this transformed list the problem is equivalent to finding the most often repeating substring before the `-` sign (this is why a single `0` as input does not work because only in that case there is no minus sign)

Answer (score 3):

### [Retina](http://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 38 bytes

```
\d+
$*
(?<=(1*) )\1

(.+?)(| \1)+$
$#2
```

Input should be space-separated.

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JShHYApcZCsKJCoKKD88PSgxKikgKVwxCgooLis_KSh8IFwxKSskCiQjMg&input=MSAzIDUgNiA4IDEwIDExIDEzIDE1IDE2IDE4IDIwCjMgNSA3IDEwIDEzIDE1CjEgMiAzCjEgMiA0CjMgNSA3IDkgMTIgMTQgMTYgMTg) (The first line enables a linefeed-separated test suite.)

#### Explanation

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert input to unary by replacing each number `n` with `n` copies of `1`.

```
(?<=(1*) )\1
```

Compute consecutive differences, by removing from each number the previous number.

```
(.+?)(| \1)+$
$#2
```

Try to match the entire input as a repetition of difference (favouring more repetitions of fewer differences) and replace it with the number of repetitions.